# Не удается применить атрибуты стиля в GWT

Tags: java, исключения, gwt

При попытке применить атрибут стиля не в camel-case формате падает исключение. Как применить атрибут, если его нельзя использовать в другом формате? например, -moz-user-select.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Еще можно написать такой метод в какой-нибудь утилитный класс:

```
public static native void setProperty(Style style, String name, String value) /*-{
  style[name] = value;
}-*/;
```

и добавлять свойство через него

```
SomeUtil.setProperty(getElement().getStyle(), "-moz-user-select", "none");
```

Comment: спасибо! это универсальный вариант

Answer (score 0):

Создай стиль в css-файле с нужным свойством

```
.stylename { 
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
```

и примени его вот так:

```
getElement().addStyle(".stylename");
```